# How do you update a Gmail draft relevant to a thread without it losing the link to the thread?

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, google-app-maker

I create a draft for an email thread in Google App Maker by using the threadId. This draft is shown as part of the thread in Gmail. However when I update the draft it loses the link it has to the thread.

The following code was used to create a reply draft to a thread and the draftId was stored.

```
var draft = GmailApp.getThreadById(threadId).createDraftReply('');
```

Then the draft is updated as below. When this is run, the link with the thread is lost. I am not keen on passing all these parameters as I just want to update the html body of the draft

```
function saveDraft(draftId, body) {
  if (draftId !== null) {
    var draftToSave = GmailApp.getDraft(draftId);
    var draftMessage = draftToSave.getMessage();
    var options = {
        'htmlBody': body,
        'cc': draftMessage.getCc(),
        'bcc': draftMessage.getBcc()
    };

    draftToSave.update(draftMessage.getTo(), draftMessage.getSubject(), '', options);
  }
}
```

I expect to update the body of the draft which is linked to the thread without changing anything else. 
Note that I am passing an html body not a text body.

Answer (score 0):

It says from this [SO post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30297/how-to-link-or-share-an-email-in-gmail),

> There is no way to get a link or to share an email or thread with
>   another person using just Gmail. Gmail gives you a [unique URL in the
>   address bar for each message thread](http://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-emails-have-permanent-web-address/6811/) but that URL is only accessible
>   after you have logged in to your account, so another user would not be
>   able to access the link.
>
> Gmail Labs has a [Create a Document](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/12/new-in-labs-turn-email-into-google-doc.html) feature but the document it creates
>   only seems to include the last email in a thread and there is no easy
>   way to copy the remainder of the thread into that document for easy
>   sharing.

This means that whenever you will try to update the draft, it will loses the link to the thread. But you could try to use search operator for this after updating your draft. Copy and store the [MessageID](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31926/how-can-i-find-a-message-by-message-id-in-gmail/35492#35492) from the header of the message then search for it. You can use the [filtering Gmail APIs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to clarify the issue further, the link is only lost when using the update() function. I checked the raw content of the draft message before and after the update. The content was reduced. I'm sure it held the data required to retain the link to the thread. However, I do not know how to pass it.